# Time series prediction: visualising path uncertainty region

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization, predictive-models

I am predicting a time series' future evolution and am evaluating the path uncertainty using bootstrapping.

Is there a good way to visualise the uncertainty that goes beyond simply plotting a pair of confidence bands, e.g. 90% lines? I thought of something that gives a better feeling for the distribution at each future time point: e.g. something like a contour plot or a plot where the level of transparency indicates the likelihood.

Also, is there a convenient way to compare two path predictions from different models visually? The only thing that comes to mind is two overlaid contour plots.

Comment: Maybe use a heat map?

Comment: My preference is for coloured contour plots, going from a deep coloured region for high certainty to pale colours for the edge of the distribution.  With transparent colours (e.g., red versus blue) you can compare two different models with some overlap and still read it.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Sounds interesting but I am having problems imaging what exactly you mean. Do you have an example plot you could post?

Answer (score 4):

*Expanding on a comment:*

My preference for showing confidence intervals is to use coloured contour plots, going from a deep coloured region for high certainty to pale colours for the edge of the distribution.  That way, you not only show the different boundaries of the confidence regions, but you also give the visual impression of a "fuzzy" region, fading from the best-prediction line to the edge of possibility.

I haven't been doing much advanced R graphics lately, so I can't help you too much with implementation, but I put together a mock-up in Javascript/D3:  http://fiddle.jshell.net/WDc3H/1/ 
[image: Example of coloured contours for confidence interval]

Because I've implemented the fading colours through transparency, you can even add in a partially-overlapping second prediction+CI set and compare the two.  How easy it is to compare will depend on how much overlap you have.  You can use the checkboxes on the above link to toggle a second series, but there is really too much overlap, and the contour lines from the different confidence intervals are more dominant than the difference in colour.

[image: Coloured contours for two lines, with heavy overlap]

It's more effective when there is greater divergence in the distributions, as in this modified example where I've extended the lines over a wider domain:
 http://fiddle.jshell.net/WDc3H/2/
[image: Coloured contours for two diverging lines]

Comment: Dazzling! I'd love to see something like this implemented via the `ggplot2` package in R, let alone research literature. Our visualizations could be so much more exciting than they are...I recognize some tradeoff with clarity of interpretations and evaluative connotations though. E.g., does red look more negative to naive readers, I wonder? Would we want to dazzle our readers with colorful visualizations even when there's relatively little "going on"? Maybe transparency and saturation could vary as well...Quite an exciting variety of possibilites implied here.

Comment: Yes, hopefully as more journals are online (and therefore less stingy of colour) and as more graphing software becomes available, you'll start seeing more possibilities with data visualization.  I do agree, you have to be careful to avoid decoration for its own sake -- the question is whether you are improving communication or not.  I think the first and third do that; for data like the second I'd recommend side-by-side plots for the comparison.

Comment: @NickStauner, check out some visually weighted regression plots in R ([1](http://is-r.tumblr.com/post/32256789836/visually-weighted-regression-plots-with-zelig),[2](http://www.nicebread.de/visually-weighted-watercolor-plots-new-variants-please-vote/)). Originally via [Solomon Hsiang](http://www.fight-entropy.com/2012/08/watercolor-regression.html). For a start on the lit. of viz. uncertainty I would recommend the paper [Spiegelhalter, David, Mike Pearson, and Ian Short. 2011. Visualizing uncertainty about the future. Science 333: 1393–1400.](http://goo.gl/RAv8wY)

Comment: Great links @AndyW.  The Nature article reminded me of a specific name for using fading colours for confidence intervals for a prediction: a "fan chart" (since the CI tend to be larger as you extrapolate farther in the future, and therefore "fan out" from the best-fit prediciton line).  Although, I like the name "watercolour chart" as a more general description.